# How can I navigate backward and forward using a Rapoo Optical Mouse?

Tags: mouse

I want to use the additional buttons of [my Rapoo N3600 Optical Mouse](http://www.rapoo.com/product/193) to navigate backward and forward in my web browser. How can I achieve this?

Comment: AD isn't very well suited for basic customer support questions, see https://apple.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/why-were-not-customer-support-for-company-x-or-product-y for details. As Rapoo claims that no additional software is required, did you already reach out to support@rapoo.com? And in case you did, what kind of answer you got?

Comment: I just wrote a mail to the support. Let me see what they will answer. The buttons are active, when I press them scrolling mode is entered. As I could not find additional software I was hoping that there is a system property that can change the behaviour of the buttons.

Comment: You might want to try [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/News.html). From the site: `The USB Overdrive is a device driver for macOS that handles any USB or Bluetooth mouse, keyboard, trackball, joystick, gamepad or gaming device from any manufacturer and lets you configure it either globally or on a per-application, per-device basis. `

Comment: Let's see what answer you get. There are already several similar questions on AD, with most answers recommending USB Overdrive. So that's probably the next stop then :-)

Comment: I looked over the  Rapoo N3600 Optical Mouse site.  not the best.  some links were dead. I was hoping to download the doc.  I think you need to download and install their mouse driver.  Standard mouse drivers support only the standard mouse buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/Download.html). I could remap **Button 4** and **Button 5**. Make sure you use **Keyboard Shortcut** and select **Back** and **Forward** from *Keyboard shortcut to type*.

[image: USB Overdrive configuration]